# How do I round the coordinates of a point before insert into attribute table in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, vbscript

Until now I doing the following steps to get rounded coordinates:

1. create a new **`x`** and **`y`** column in the attribute table
2. use [**`Calculate Geometry`**](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0108/tip.html)
3. round the column value with the [**`Field Calculator`**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_field_calculations/005s00000025000000/) using VBS 
   `round([x],0)` and `round([y],0)`.

**How do I round the coordinates of a point before insert into attribute table in ArcGIS?**

Comment: How are you inserting the point?

Comment: Yes in the point coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using Python for calculating the coordinates.

Create a field of Double type. Right-click the field and choose Field Calculator. Then choose Python for the Parser option.

For X field:

```
round(!SHAPE.CENTROID.X!,2)
```

For Y field:

```
round(!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!,2)
```

Will give you a field with a integer of double precision rounded to two digits after the comma.

If you want to preserve the raw values, but have them just show as if they were rounded, you can modify the properties of the field.

[image]

Look at some other samples for geometry calculations with Python [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/).

Comment: That's what I was looking for thx!

Comment: Did you read "round the coordinates of a point before insert into attribute table" as "round the coordinates of a point before *update using them in the* attribute table"?  I thought this must have been a question needing an insert cursor, or that there was an unmentioned add of a point via the Editor toolbar.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am pretty sure the questioner has a point feature class and just wants to have a couple of fields calculated.